# CSS stylesheet value is not modifying

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function getStyle(Selector, Property, Value, StyleSheetIndex) {    
    var Selectors = document.styleSheets[StyleSheetIndex].rules;    
    for (var i = 0; i < Selectors.length; i++) {
        if (Selectors[i].selectorText == Selector) {            
            alert(Value +  "     " + Property);
            Selectors[i].style[Property] = "url(" + Value + ")"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Where Selector = "body", Property="backgroundImage", value="/images/bg.jpg",StyleSheetIndex = 2,
but here the property value is not changing.Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: are you trying to edit the actual file or the style on the webpage?

Comment: then you need to use a server side language like PHP, javascript cannot edit files.

Comment: ok , but whats the problem in this case?

Comment: if the css is being used in the document and it's displaying the changes on the webpage, then nothing, but you need to at least call to a php page to handle the files if you want them edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged `jQuery` to this question I would suggest you to go simple using jQuery. Try this.

```
$('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url("/images/bg.jpg")');
```

As a side note since this method sets the style it should be named as `setStyle` instead of `getStyle`.

Comment: ok i agree jquery as u mention is easy than the code which i had written but can u tell me the problem why it is not changing the bgImage?